# What is the time complexity of passing a Vector of size n to another function by passing by value and passing by reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
void fun(vector<int>vec)
{
   some code
}
int main()
{
   int n = 5;
   vector<int>avec(n);
   fun(avec);
}
```

What is the time complexity of passing a Vector of size `n` to another function by passing by value and passing by reference?
What is the time complexity of this code passing a vector only one time?

Comment: Do you know the difference between passing by value and passing by reference?

Comment: What's your understanding of the complexity? Any guesses?

Comment: to copy n elements you need to copy n elements. Note that it only makes sense to speak of complexity in dependence of n when n can actually grow. Copying a vector of size 5 once is of constant complexity ;)

Answer (score 3):

Passing a `std::vector` of size `N` to a function by value obviously has a linear complexity `O(n)`, since it involves copying `N` objects. Passing by reference has complexity `O(1)`, since in fact only the address of the object `std::vector` is passed to the function, regardless of its size.

It is worth noting that the situation is different with returning a `std::vector` from a function, in this case, returning by value has a complexity of `O(1)`, since in this case the compiler either uses [`copy elision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) , if it is permitted, or the [move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) constructor. Both has `O(1)` compexity.